# Session issue with two application on same server?

Tags: php, session, session-state

There I have an issue with application session data.
I host them on the same server but when I log out from one of them then second's session also unset and application logs out automatically.
Please provide the information what's wrong I am doing here and help me to rise from this one.
 The code used by for unset the session for my application is.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Don't use same session name on same server...

Comment: @yash I already use the different name for the sessions but still happening the same.

Comment: Show me how you are destroying session in both applications with name...

Comment: there am using above code to destroy them not by there name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue this because of Sessions are stored using cookies, and cookies are domain-specific. That's why these variables have the same effect on both websites and session_id also be the same for both because this kind of variables not initialized only assigned.

So, it doesn't have any issue uses the same session name as your app; your cookies are only readable/usable by the domains you specify. Even in the unusual scenario that sessions are managed in some other way, it will be domain-specific.

> Note: There must be a difference in your session variable name so that
>   not affect other site session values.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information :-

`session_unset();` deletes only the variables from session - session still exists. Only data is truncated.
`session_destroy();` is deleting the whole session.

You can also try `unset($_SESSION['VAR_NAME'])'` and then flush the session.
It will be better and good practice of removing the session by name instead of deleting the session...

Comment: sorry but I already aware of the working of these function but these affect the other application too that's the problem.